# drawing a circle of radius R around a point

Tags: gnuplot, geometry

I'm using gnuplot, and I wonder if it is possible to draw a circle of radius R around a given point (x,y) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't want to graph a circle, you can use the `set object circle` command.  You use it like this, for example:

```
set object X circle at axis 0,0 size scr 0.1 fc rgb "navy"
```

This will draw a navy blue circle at the origin with a radius of 0.1 of the screen (canvas) size.  Note that when you specify a position/radius for the circle you have to specify which coordinate system you are using: `first` corresponds to the first x-y coordinate system, `scr` (short for `screen`) is for screen coordinates.  You can learn more by looking in the documentation for drawing circles.

Comment: In this case, you may also want `set size ratio -1` as gnuplot will draw a circle regardless of the plots aspect ratio.

Comment: andyras @mgilson it is not possible to specify an "empty" circle of a certain specified radius (e.g. a radius of 2.74) ?

Comment: Ah it works with "set object 1 circle at 6,6 size first 2.73 fc rgb "navy"". Now if I have many points (in a txt file where each line is x y) and I want to draw a circles which different specified radius for each point. Should I repeat the command "set object i circle at Xi,Yi size first Ri fc rgb "navy"" for each point i ?!

Comment: @user995434 -- You should probably post that as a new question.

Comment: undefined variable: X; then undefined variable: axis

Answer (score 5):

> Now if I have many points (in a txt file where each line is x y) and I want to draw a circles which different specified radius for each point. Should I repeat the command "set object i circle at Xi,Yi size first Ri fc rgb "navy"" for each point i ?!

Answer: No!
Plotting `with circles` was available in gnuplot V4.4 (2010).

`"Circles.dat"`

```
1 1 0.1
2 2 0.2
3 3 0.3
4 4 0.4
5 5 0.5
6 6 0.6
```

**Code:**

```
plot "Circles.dat" u 1:2:3:1 w circles lc var notitle
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.4)

[image]

Comment: Nice, but the original question is about a single circle.

Comment: well, in the comments the OP asks for many points in a datafile. See quotation.

Answer (score 1):

Working gnuplot script:

```
# tell gnuplot where we want to look at
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]

# make a square plot
set size square

# create a black circle at center (0.5, 0.5) with radius 0.5
set object 1 circle front at 0.5,0.5 size 0.5 fillcolor rgb "black" lw 1

f(x) = x # we need to plot at lest one function
plot f(x) # show the stuff
```